# A small calculation .

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation

How

$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^n\times(-1)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k$

i got it

$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^n\times(-1)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{2n-k}$

And

is that $\mathbb E[\mathbb E(X)]=\mathbb E(X)$ ?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k=\frac{(-1)^{n}+1}{2}$$

Comment: Do you mean $E$ as in expectation?

Comment: @Ethan i wished to know how can i derive $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k$ from the Left hand side?

Comment: @AD. yes $\mathbb E$ is *Expectation*.

Comment: @harry Just note that $(-1)^{2n}=1$ and $(-1)^{-k}=(-1)^{k}$ for all integers $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @harry $$\sum_{k=0}^nx^k=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: As AD. notes, it is not just that the two _sums_ are equal in value but for each value of $k$, the corresponding terms in both the summations are equal.  And _expectation_ has nothing to do with it since neither $(-1)^n$ nor $(-1)^{n-k}$ can be a value of a probability mass function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1.: $(-1)^{2n-k} = (-1)^{2(n-k)+k} = ((-1)^2)^{n-k}(-1)^k = 1^{n-k}(-1)^k = (-1)^k$. So:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{2n-k}$$

More generally, $(-1)^p$ depends only on the parity of $p$. Hence if $p$ and $p'$ have the same parity, then $(-1)^p = (-1)^{p'}$. In particular, $(-1)^p=(-1)^{-p}$ and $(-1)^p = (-1)^{p+2q}$.

---

Ad 2.: $\Bbb E[X]$ is a number, a constant, say $N$; hence $\Bbb E[\Bbb E[X]] = \Bbb E[N] = N = \Bbb E[X]$.

Answer (score 0):

1: Just note that $(−1)^{2n}=1$ and $(−1)^{−k}=(−1)^k$ for all integers $n$ and $k$.

2: We have a probability measure $P$ such that
$$\int_\Omega dP(x) = 1,\qquad E(X)=\int_\Omega xdP(x)$$
and then 
$$E(E(X))=\int_\Omega E(X)dP(y)= E(X) \int_\Omega dP(y)=E(X)$$
because $E(X)$ is a constant.